# How to assign the generated id to Http Request when it completes the previous response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, http

[image]So my problem little bit tricky so here is the scenario  2 Thread Group are running simultaneously   one consisting about user Login and 2 user login at time   and request for ride and two  pickup id is generated(i stored pick up id using Regular expression and pass it other thread group to next Driver thread group using beanshell assertion) from that request and in another thread group only one driver will login and and he got 2 request and he accept the one request and complete the trip still on more request is pending now the question is how to make him accept pending request  and complete trip is this possible in jmeter please help me how to do this one .with simple example  and added image to understand the problem clearly

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [Inter-Thread communication plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/). Extract pickup id in postprocessor in TG 1. Then put pickup id to FIFO in Inter Thread communication postprocessor. Next in TG 2 get this pick up id in Inter Thread preprocessor. See examples on plugin page

Comment: hi ...how to assign the  generated pickup one by one to single request..... is there any way...?

Comment: means once pickupid is generated from request i want to hold it in queue and assign it for next request is this possible